# insert a row specific data - vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with huge data in it. Data is divided in set of rows. After every set there is a blank row. I am looking for a macro that can run through all data, and after each set of data > in the blank row it should put as shown below.

For Example

```
00059803        20-35-32    GBP 02/09/2014  Close
00005486        20-35-32    GBP 02/09/2014  Close
00004856        20-35-32    GBP 02/09/2014  Close

----------------    ------------ ----------------               

04586680        20-45-05    GBP 02/09/2014  Close
45866485        20-45-05    GBP 02/09/2014  Close
45806654        20-45-05    GBP 02/09/2014  Close

-----------------   ------------- ---------------               

00485548        20-48-42    GBP 02/09/2014  Close
04586455        20-48-42    GBP 02/09/2014  Close
00004458        20-48-42    GBP 02/09/2014  Close

-----------------   -------------  --------------
```

I want to insert " ---  ---- -----" after every set of data with macro. 
Please advise a macro code.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Use the macro recorder to get started. We will gladly help modify for your needs if you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
Sub PutInDashes()
finalRow = cells(65000,1).end(xlup).row
for i = 1 to finalRow
  if isempty(cells(i,1)) then
    for j = 1 to 5
      cells(i,j) = "--------"
    next j
  end if
next i
end sub
```

Though it's difficult to see what columns you want dashes from what you've posted, this code will put them in the first 5 columns where there are blank cells in a row.

Comment: Thanks Matt, your code does work only if i have few empty rows at the top of the sheet. It insert dashed on in those rows then it stops. If there is now blank row at the top of the sheet then this does work at all. Please advise. I want the macro to check the whole sheet and fill blank rows under each data set with dashes. Hopefully I make sense of what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: Dashes in 5 column is fine I just want dashes in few cells to differentiate data. Basically data is in few hundred rows but it is in sets i.e. a set of data in 10 rows> then three blank rows > another in set of data in 5 rows > then three blank rows > and onwards. What I want is macro should analyse the data, and under every set of data in the blank row it should put dashes.

Comment: @Kaiser did you see my last question? I am curious as to how many rows in your data set. If more than 65,000, then replace `finalRow = cells(65000,1).end(xlup).row` with something like `finalRow = cells(1000000,1).end(xlup).row`.

Comment: Hi Matt. I have worked it out with your code. actualy first column of my data was blank so code was not working. I have deleted the blank column and your macro seems to work fine. Thanks

Comment: Good. That was going to be my next question. Glad it worked for you. Cheers.

Comment: You could use `finalRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1` instead of `finalRow = cells(65000,1).end(xlup).row` to avoid missing rows.